# Ktor 2 HttpClient webSocket генерирует HttpRequestTimeoutException при использовании CIO

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

Пробую получать обновления с биржи Binance по веб сокету и да же на простейшем случае получаю
HttpRequestTimeoutException. Вот пример кода

```
    class TestEmptyWebsocket: Subcommand("${Contracts.PREFIX}-test-empty-web-socket", "Test empty web socket") {

    private val webSocketHost: String = "stream.binance.com"
    private val webSocketPort: Int = 9443
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = newSingleThreadContext("test-binance")
    private val rootJob = Job()

    private val currentScope = CoroutineScope(dispatcher + rootJob)
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger(TestEmptyWebsocket::class.java.canonicalName)

    private val webSocketClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(WebSockets) {
            pingInterval= 1000
        }
        install(HttpTimeout){
            requestTimeoutMillis=10000
        }
        defaultRequest {
            url {
                host = webSocketHost
                protocol = URLProtocol.WSS
                port = webSocketPort

            }
        }
    }

    override fun execute()= runBlocking {
        val thirdJob = currentScope.launch {
            val startTime=Clock.System.now()
            try {

                webSocketClient.webSocket(
                    request = {
                        url {
                            protocol = URLProtocol.WSS
                            encodedPath = "/stream?streams=sysbtc@depth@100"
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    while (true) {
                        when (val incoming = incoming.receive()) {
                            is Frame.Text -> logger.info { "get text ${incoming.readText()}" }
                            else -> logger.info { "get not text frame" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (ex:HttpRequestTimeoutException){
                logger.error(ex) { "stop coroutine after ${(Clock.System.now()-startTime).inWholeMilliseconds} ms" }
                this.cancel()
            }
        }
        thirdJob.join()
    }
}
```

При этом получаю сообщение *stop coroutine after 10015 ms* То есть через timeout который сам установил.
Использую ktor версии **ktorVersion=2.0.2**. В проекте подключены следующие зависимости

```
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
```

Вопрос, как сделать так, что бы Ktor клиент ждал дольше данного timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

Добавил вот такой код перестало вылетать

```
install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = HttpTimeout.INFINITE_TIMEOUT_MS
}
```